# "?" instead of "-" in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql, collation

I have hardcoded value, which I inserted (using SQL script) into SQL Server 2008R2:

> 'Full - loans'

but I see ? instead of - in the table:

> 'Full ? loans'

Parameters of column:

> varchar(50), cp1250, Polish_CI_AS

How to display this dash correctly?

Comment: Is that a normal dash? Seems like it's some kind of unicode character. Try changing column to nvarchar if possible and see if that helps..

Comment: @Tobb This is "standard" dash, harcoded in SSMS.

Comment: Works for me with SSMS (sqlserver express)..  but could you try the same with a unicode column (nvarchar) and see if you get the same result?

Comment: What is in you question is the normal - from the keyboard.   Copy paste from your question and see if that inserts correctly.  You will get a ? if the character is not in the code page with varchar.

Comment: @Tobb Yes, it's works after changing column type.

Comment: Then I strongly doubt that the dash is a regular hyphen character, might be a long (em) hyphen or something..

Comment: try running SELECT ASCII ( '-'),ASCII ( SUBSTRING(<yourColumn>,6,1)) FROM yourtable WHERE (yourColumn from the row with the issue) if the numbers match then they are the same character. If not then you know that you must have some funny character in there. referenced from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms177545.aspx